# Is there a way in .NET MAUI use multiple components components in one place?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have a view which has some state and based on that state we want to use dynamically one of 3 component to show.
I know that we could allways hide 2 of them and show only one, but I am looking for a way to create property of in parent viewmodel in which would be stored instance of particular view we want to show. So whenever I would change that property, it would rerender itself with new component.
My main downfall is that I have no idea how to render property with stored view in XAML.

I was looking in microsoft docs, but honestly i have no idea what to look for.

Comment: Hi, you could share some code about what you've done and what you want to achieve, which might help us understand your question better.

Answer (score 2):

If I got your issue right, what you're looking for are [data templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/datatemplate?view=net-maui-7.0)

> A `DataTemplate` is used to specify the appearance of data, and typically uses data binding to display data.

Since in your case the appearance (i.e. the data template) depends on the data to present, you will need a [data template selector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/datatemplate?view=net-maui-7.0#create-a-datatemplateselector)

> A `DataTemplateSelector` can be used to choose a `DataTemplate` at runtime based on the value of a data-bound property.

I will try and come up with an example and might edit this answer later to present the example.

Answer (score 1):

You could create multiple [ContentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/contentview?view=net-maui-7.0) components with xaml UI and bind them with their own ViewModel. Then on the page you want to display your custom component create generic ContentView element and bind it's Content to ViewModel property.

```
<ContentView Content="{Binding Content}"/>
```

Then in your ViewModel create ObservableProperty using [MVVM community toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/introduction) or just implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
[ObservableProperty]
private ContentView content;
```

Now you can get your prepared components using Dependency Injection.

```
private readonly CustomView1 _customView1;
private readonly CustomView2 _customView2;

public ViewModel(CustomView1 customView1, CustomView2 customView2)
{
    _customView1 = customView1;
    _customView2 = customView2;
}
```

Now you can simply change your displayed Component in your ViewModel by changing your binded property "Content"

```
Content = _customView1;
```